# Two radio buttons, when false stay selected?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button

I have the following class for filtering, two bool values as shown here

```
 public class ProductFilter
 {
    public bool Tubs { get; set; }
    public bool Packs { get; set; }
 }
```

Which on my view are laid out as follows

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Products", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row col-lg-12" id="filters">
        <div class="col-lg-4 text-right">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Filter.Tubs, Model.Filter.Tubs) Tubs
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 text-left">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Filter.Packs, Model.Filter.Packs) Packs
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When selecting either of them the following script is called

```
$('#Filter_Tubs,#Filter_Packs').click(function () {
  var checked = $(this).attr('checked', true);
  alert(checked);
  if (checked) {
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
  } else {
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
  }
  this.form.submit();
});
```

now when I select/un-select them I get true or false in the controller which is working as expected, yet when I return back to the view they stay selected even though the value for Tubs and Packs are false? why?

I even done this in my controller to see if it un-selects them

```
viewModel.Filter.Tubs = false;
viewModel.Filter.Packs = false;
```

but with no avail.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought this was addressed in my answer to your last question? Why would you use a radio button to represent a `bool`?. In any case `$(this).attr('checked', false);` does not do anything with respect to changing the value that's posted back (it's the `value` attribute that's posted back so you would need something like `$(this).val("True");` and of course `viewModel.Filter.Tubs = false;` is doing exactly what your telling it to do, which is to select it!

Comment: To expand on the last point, the first parameter means your binding to property `Tubs` which is `false`, and the second parameter sets the `value` attribute to `value="false"`. Since they are the same, its selected (exactly the same would happen if your set `Tubs=true;` - it would be selected)